# Delete a record from database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database

I'm trying to delete record from data base MSSQL by entering the ID and hit delete btn. i didn't get any error and it give recorded deleted successful but once i check database i see the record doesn't deleted

```
protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (txtImgID.Text == "")
        {

            Response.Write("Enter Image Id To Delete");
        }
        else
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();

            con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GMSConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

            con.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from certf where id=" + txtImgID.Text + "", con);

            lblsubmitt.Text = "Data Deleted Sucessfully";
        }
    }

    catch (Exception)
    {
        lblsubmitt.Text = "You haven't Submited any data";
    }
}
```

Comment: A command needs to be executed to do anything. You don't execute the command. Add cmd.ExecuteNonQuery. But before doing this I really suggest you to learn how to use parameterized queries. What do you think will happen if someone writes in that textbox _1 OR 1=1_?

Comment: Worst "error handling" ever. Plus: [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) prone.

Comment: `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` is missing

Answer (score 0):

```
var idToDelete = int.Parse(txtImgID.Text); // this is not necessary if the data type in the DB is actually a string

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GMSConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM [certf] WHERE id = @id", con))
{
  // I am assuming that id is an integer but if it is a varchar/string then use the line below this one
  // cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = txtImgID.Text;
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int32).Value = idToDelete;
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

1. You need to call [ExecuteNonQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?view=netframework-4.7.2) which executes the query against the database.
2. Always use parameters instead of string concatenation in your queries. It guards against sql injection and ensures you never has issues with strings that contain escape characters.
3. I did not include any error handling or return messages but do note that you are throwing away all the good stuff in your excetion handler's catch block, you will never know why a query failed after this has executed.

Comment: @user2478347 - glad to help. Please consider marking an answer using the checkmark on the left side if this solves your problem.